# Yandex Map Kit для Unity

Tags: unity3d, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

Я сейчас открываю карту на Webview в Unity. Но есть ли package для Unity, чтобы без использования WebView работать с картамы

Comment: Яндекс сам такое писать не будет, как не пишет и для других фреймворков. Сторонние варианты можно поискать в сети. Первый попавшийся - https://github.com/ARtronClassicStudio/YandexMapsUnity

Comment: Спасибо, линк уже видел, но он статичный

Comment: Ну сценарий платный (карта Яндекс без сайта), потому разработчики не очень желают, видимо, делиться этим нахаляву. Надо искать решения на картах, которые не запрещают встраивать себя куда-попало бесплатно.